# How to display error message in multi file uploading with Rest webservices

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

Hi am in way of uploading multiple files into aws bucket using spring mvc and rest web services. 
The positive scenario is working like if I select more one file its saved in aws bucket and am getting  200 here
 String json1 = handler.handleResponse(response1);
System.out.println(json1);

My question is I have selected three files called x ,y and z as usual way the first file gets saved into bucket due to some issue y and z files failed to save how to inform the user that y and z are not saved into bucket

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("specifications") MultipartFile[] specifications,        
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws       Exception {


for (int i = 0; i < specifications.length; i++) {
                MultipartFile file = specifications[i];            
                String path = "Specification/";                
                String bucketName="BUcket/";
                String inJson = "{\"filename\":\"" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "\",\"bucketname\":\""+ bucketName + "\",\"path\":\""+ path + "\"}";
                addLogo(file, inJson);
            }
```

**code upload file**

```
public void addLogo(MultipartFile file ,String inJson) throws IOException
    {
        String message="";
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(fileUploadURL);
        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addTextBody("json", inJson).addBinaryBody("file", bytes).build();
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.print(response1.getStatusLine());
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String json1 = handler.handleResponse(response1);
        System.out.println(json1);
        message = message + "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "\n";
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

by using ResponseEntity spring object, you can customize your returns based upload results. you catch IOEXception and create a specific return String,
I modified your method to be like this :

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
            public ResponseEntity<?> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("specifications") 
            MultipartFile[] specifications,        
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session,final RedirectAttributes 
            redirectAttributes) throws Exception {

            String failed_upload="";
            for (int i = 0; i < specifications.length; i++) {
                        try{
        MultipartFile file = specifications[i];            
                        String path = "Specification/";                
                        String bucketName="BUcket/";
                        String inJson = "{\"filename\":\"" + file.getOriginalFilename() 
            + "\",\"bucketname\":\""+ bucketName + "\",\"path\":\""+ path + "\"}";
                        addLogo(file, inJson);
        }catch(IOException){
            failed_upload=failed_upload+specifications[i]+" ,";
            }

        } if(!failed_upload.equals("")){
           return new ResponseEntity<>("Files"+failed_upload+" not uploaded", 
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
         }else{
       return new ResponseEntity<>("Everything is ok", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```